# Cyrillic characters in friendly URLs not working with IIS

Tags: php, iis, url-rewrite-module, isapi-rewrite, cyrillic

I am building a WordPress website which is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5

For Fancy URLs I am using web.config file with URL Rewrite 2.0

The URLs like **website.com/my-page** work fine.
The problem is when I have Russian or any Cyrillic characters in url - ( like **website.com/сито-для-угля/** ) wordpress can't find the page.

**Note:** *These URLs work fine in WAMP. Problem is when hosted in IIS 7.5*

- I have tried ISAPI Rewrite module for IIS too, but still same problem.
- I have tried to disable any kind of rewriting ( url rewrite module and ISAPI rewrite module )  but still the Cyrillic  characters in URL are received as ???-???-??? in my index.php file of wordpress.
- Also I tried **website.com/index.php?page=сито-для-угля**, this gives me **сито-для-угля** correctly in index.php. Problem is only for friendly URLs.

So this seems to be IIS issue? Any one knows how to fix this?

Comment: You can try using NE or NU flags in ISAPI_Rewrite3 to deal with this.